# Contents get refreshed after the popup is opened

Tags: php, html

I have a form wich has various fields.and i have a button 'GET REPORT'.on pressing this button the required contents are displayed in the table.in table i have a column called as images,which is a link to the image.when i press the link, popup appears with the image.my problem is, on clicking the popup the image appears but the page gets refreshed.i want it to stay on the same page even after the pop up is opened and closed.

This is my table,values are fetched from the database

```
 <table id="sourceAnalysisTable" >
                <thead id="headings">
                    <tr>
                        <td ><h3>Reported Date<h3></td>
                        <td><h3>Status<h3></td>
                        <td><h3>Address</h3></td>
                        <td><h3>Images<h3></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                for($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++)
                    {


                        $dmydate = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($ARRAY[$i]['source_visitDate']));
                        echo'<td>'.$dmydate.'</td>';
                        echo'<td>'.$ARRAY[$i]['source_status'].'</td>';
                        echo'<td>'.$ARRAY[$i]['source_address'].'</td>';
                        echo'<td>';

    ?>
    /*here image names are given as link and #openModal is id to  popup*/
    <a href="?source_id=<?php echo $ARRAY[$i]["source_id"] ?>&#openModal" ><?php echo $ARRAY[$i]["source_photo"] ?> </a>

        <?php
    echo '</td>';
    echo'</tr>';

    }
/*get report button*/
<input type="submit" name="GETREPORT" value="Get Report" id="btnreport" />
```

This is how my image names are taken from the database and showed in popup.

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
        <div>
        <a href="#" onclick="window.close();opener.window.focus()" class="closeno">X</a>

        <div id="makeMeScrollable">
    <?php

    $id=$_GET['source_id'];

    $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT source_photo FROM source_main where source_id ='$id'");
    while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
    {

    $result['image'] = trim($result['source_photo'],'\,');

    $temp = explode(',',$result['source_photo'] );

    $temp = array_filter($temp);

    foreach($temp as $image){
        $images[]="images/demo/".trim( str_replace( array('[',']') ,"" ,$image ) );
    } 
    } 
    foreach($images as $image){

      //if(is_file(ROOTDIR.$image))
        echo "<img src='{$image}' height='250' width='280' />";
    }
    ?>

    </div></div></div>
```

How can i do this..please help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Give your links a class, and use javascript to target links of that class:

```
/*here image names are given as link and #openModal is id to  popup*/
<a class="no-default-action" href="?source_id=<?php echo $ARRAY[$i]["source_id"] ?>&#openModal" ><?php echo $ARRAY[$i]["source_photo"] ?> </a>
```

AND

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
    <a class="no-default-action closeno" href="#" onclick="window.close();opener.window.focus()">X</a>

    <div id="makeMeScrollable">
```

Throw in this bit of Javascript:

```
<script>
 var targetLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".no-default-action");
 for(var x in targetLinks)
 {
    targetLinks[x].attachEventListener("click", function(e)
    {
       if(typeof e.preventDefault !== 'undefined'){
        e.preventDefault();
       }
       else{
        e.returnValue = false;
       }

    }, false);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: actually what is happening is i have a condition if the data is not found in the database based on the date, it displays the msg "no record found".so when i press the image link it gets refreshed to today's date(i dont hv any data with today's date) and displays the msg not found. i want it to remain as it is..so please help

Comment: Show me the line(s) that contain the link to be clicked.

Comment: <a  href="?source_id=<?php echo $ARRAY[$i]["source_id"] ?>&#openModal" ><?php echo $ARRAY[$i]["source_photo"] ?> </a>...this one

Comment: Then try like so: `/*here image names are given as link and #openModal is id to  popup*/
    <a href="?source_id=<?php echo $ARRAY[$i]['source_id']; ?>&#openModal" onclick="return false;" ><?php echo $ARRAY[$i]['source_photo'] ?> </a>` Note where I used single quotes. Let me know if it works

Comment: Remove the `onclick=return false;` and try it with my earlier provided answer, with the single quotes I just used